# Setting up Mailgun with Meteor JS on Heroku - Error 554

Tags: javascript, meteor, heroku, mailgun

I've been trying to set up my mailgun to work with my Meteor app. When I use the sandbox, it works perfectly, but when I use the custom domain, I get an error:

```
 Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' DeliveryError: Message delivery failed: 554 The domain is unverified and requires DNS configuration. Log in to your control panel to view required DNS records.
```

I've set up my configurations, so when I `heroku config` on the cmd, I get my vars and they're all correct.

```
MAILGUN_API_KEY:       key-<api>
MAILGUN_DOMAIN:        <appname>.herokuapp.com
MAILGUN_PUBLIC_KEY:    pubkey-<key>
MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN:    postmaster@<appname>.herokuapp.com
MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD: <password>
MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT:     587
```

I've also set my app's environment variables in `server/server.js` like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://postmaster%40<appname>.herokuapp.com:<password>@smtp.mailgun.org:587';
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think that error is coming from Mailgun, not Heroku.

Comment: Yeah @CodeChimp, I think so too. That's the error I'm trying to resolve but I can't figure out why it's occurring.

Comment: No expert here, but in googling it seems that you have to somehow register your Heroku server w/ Mailgun through the control panel.  I think, from what I gathered via the postings I read, that Mailgun may have enacted some new security features to tighten security some.